# Vue PWA blank screen after closing the app

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-app, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA Application and it works fine.

> Problem is:

User installing the PWA on Desktop and it works fine but after closing and re-opening it show blank page.

Also on mobile it show blank page after adding the website to home page.

var deferredPrompt;

***LINK***

https://gogrocery.tk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is with the `manifest.json` `start_url`.

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "short_name": "front-end",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#4DBA87"
}
```

Once installed the browser users `index.html` as the starting URL and that doesn't render the app. You should either change `start_url` to `/` or have `/index.html` render the app.

Answer (score 7):

Add a route for '/index.html' into your default router. Use the same view/component as for '/'

```
...
    routes: [
        { path: '/', name: 'home', component: HomeView },
        { path: '/index.html', component: HomeView }, // Fix for PWA at /index.html
...
```

Note: Don't use redirect for '/index.html', it doesn't fix the problem on mobile browsers :(

Comment: You just saved us after weeks of speculating and trying. Thank you!!

Comment: You can also use a default route instead of writing two routes
{
      path: '*',
      name: 'HomeDefault',
      component: HomeView,
    },